# How to extract or grab all shortened URLs from a tweet?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, twitter, web-scraping

I want to extract shortened URLs from tweets if any. These URLs follow a standard form:http://t.co ([details here](https://support.twitter.com/articles/109623))

For this, I used the following regex expression which works fine when I tested it with tweet text by just storing the text as a string.

**NOTE:** 
I am using https://shortnedurl/string instead of the real shortened URL because StackOverflow does not allow posting such URLs here.

Sample code:

```
import re

tweet = "Grim discovery in the USS McCain collision probe https://shortnedurl.com @MattRiversCNN reports #TheLead"

urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+',
                  tweet)
for url in urls:
    print "printing urls", url
```

The output of this code:

```
printing urls https://shortnedurl.com
```

However, when I read the tweet from twitter using its API and run the same regex on it, I get the following output which is undesirable.

```
printing urls https://https://shortnedurl/string
printing urls https://https://shortnedurl/string</a></span>
printing urls https://twitter.com/MattRiversCNN
printing urls https://twitter.com/search?q=%23TheLead
```

It seems like it's getting the URL for twitter ID, as well as a hashtag.

How can I deal with this problem? I just want to read only these http://t.co URLs.

**UPDATE1:** 
I tried https?://t.co/\S*, however, I am still getting the following noisy url:

```
printing urls https://https://shortnedurl/string
printing urls https://https://shortnedurl/string>https://https://shortnedurl/string</a></span>
```

I do not know why the same URL is found again with the `</a><span>`.

For the https?://t.co/\S+, I get invalid URLs because it combines both of these above URLs in one:

```
printing urls https://https://shortnedurl/string>https://https://shortnedurl/string</a></span>
```

**Update2:**
**The tweet text looks a bit different what I expected:**

```
    Grim discovery in the USS McCain collision probe 
<span class="link"><a href="https://shortenedurl">https://shortenedurl</a></span> <span class="username"><a 
href="https://twitter.com/MattRiversCNN">@MattRiversCNN</a></span>
     reports <span class="tag"><a href="https://twitter.com/search?
    q=%23TheLead">#TheLead</a></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the regex

```
https?://t\.co/\S+
```

Comment: S+ does not work. It combines the two normal url with the noisy url in one string which leads to an invalid url. See the update.

Comment: I think it has to do with a normal string and the tweet text form. see my update 2.

Comment: "(https?:\/\/shortnedurl\.com\/\S+)" will match it along with the "", you can remove  the "" in another step

Comment: I am accepting your answer. Maybe it's a good idea to add these comments to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, just put the string you want to have contained in your regex, like so:

```
https?://shortnedurl.com/\S*
# look for http or https:://
# shortnedurl.com/ literally
# followed by anything not a whitespace character, 0+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/fTdq5X/2).
For your special case:

```
https?://t\.co/\S*
```